# CS50 Caesar segmentation fault

Tags: c, cs50

I am new here and working on the second homework Caesar of cs50, it seems most of my review is correct except the last one -- I cannot handle the situation of lacking argv[1], which means if I only type ./caesar, it will return segmentation fault. I am wondering why this code `if (argc != 2)` cannot return 0 when argc == 1, however it works when argc > 1, I find that is weird. Can anyone help me?? Thanks in advance!

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <cs50.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <ctype.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <stdlib.h>



int check_the_key(int argc, string y);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string x = argv[1];
    int y = argc;
    int k = check_the_key(y, x);

    if (k == 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR!!!!!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // printf("The key is %i\n", k);

        string text = get_string("Input your text:");
        int i;
        int n;
        printf("ciphertext: ");
        for (i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (islower(text[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (text[i] - 97 + k) % 26 + 97 );
            }
            else if (isupper(text[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (text[i] - 65 + k) % 26 + 65);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", text[i]);
            }

        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;


    }

}

int check_the_key(int argc, string y)
{   
    int number = argc;
    string key = y;
    int numberkey = atoi(key);

    if (argc != 2)
    {

        return 0;
    }

    else 
    {
        if (numberkey > 0)
        {
            return numberkey;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what is going on! Because I need to pass some value into `atoi()`, if I only call ./caesar, there is no value I can pass into `atoi()`, so it causes segmentation fault. Which means I need to change code order slightly, put `int numberkey = atoi(key);` inside the else loop. So the code will run `if (argc != 2)` first, if no, then go to the next step! Here is the code after change.

```
int check_the_key(int argc, string y)
{   
    int number = argc;
    string key = y;


    if (argc != 2)
    {

        return 0;
    }

    else 
    {
        int numberkey = atoi(key);
        if (numberkey > 0)
        {
            return numberkey;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }


}
```